# Can't find qml module related to vlc

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I cloned the vlc repository and I'm trying to modify the qt interface.

I stumbled upon this file [MainInterface.qml](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/master/modules/gui/qt/maininterface/qml/MainInterface.qml) which has a particular line:

```
import org.videolan.vlc 0.1
```

I can't help finding this module. I understood it's related to some other qmldir file but I don't understand where it might be.

Qt Creator doesn't show me the design panel because it can't find the module.

So, where do I find this module? Am I supposed to download some package?

(Working on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the module is defined in on the C++ side, it contains type registration for various models and types used in the QML interface

the module definition is here:

https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/blob/4955734f1c3559a2a1315fc674a1d094c04d9692/modules/gui/qt/maininterface/mainui.cpp#L173

Comment: Thank you so much! You were really helpful!
Just one last question: if I want to learn more about this qml/c++ thing, what should I look for?

Comment: you can look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-overview.html regarding how C++/QML intergation works and https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html regarding how models are exposed.